# PHP try Catch not catching a runtime exception

Tags: php, wordpress

I had an exception that vaporised WordPress with no error and just a blank page output. I tried to add the Try Catch below so that I could see the error message!

```
function UpdateSlugFieldsForTrainings(int $post_id = null, int $parent_id = null )
{
    
    try
    {
        if (is_null($parent_id))
        {
            $parent_id = toolset_get_related_post( $post_id, 'courses_trainings' );
        }
        
        $parent_post = get_post( $parent_id );
        $parent_slug = $parent_post->post_name;
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'parent_slug', $parent_slug );
        
        $pcategories = get_the_terms( $parent_id, 'course-category' );
        if ( ! empty( $pcategories ) ) {
            $pcategory = $pcategories[0]->slug; 
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'parent_course_category_slug', $pcategory );
        }
        // wpcf-code
        $coursecode = get_post_meta( $parent_id, 'wpcf-code', true );
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'parent_code', $coursecode );
        
        // wpcf-event-date
        $trainingStartDatetimestamp = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-event-date', true );
        if(!empty($trainingStartDatetimestamp))
        {
          $trainingStartDate  = date('Y-m-d', $trainingStartDatetimestamp);
          update_post_meta($post_id, 'training_friendly_date', $trainingStartDate );
        }       
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        // do nothing... php will ignore and continue
        // but maybe use "ignored" as name to silence IDE warnings.  
        error_log($ex->getMessage());
    }

}
```

However no catch was caught!

With dudicious application of `error_log` and `return;` I was able to figure out that it was  `date('Y-m-d', $trainingStartDatetimestamp);` when `$trainingStartDatetimestamp` was empty.

While I have added the wrapper for `empty` I would like to understand why the `Try catch` does not do what I expect a `Try catch` to do?

Comment: Providing *actual error message* usually helps

Comment: `ini_set('log_errors', 1);` in case for some reason PHP isn't configured to log errors already.

Comment: @YourCommonSense there is no error message that makes it anywhere. As specific the application (Wordpress) just fails to render and writes noting to the logs.